# Java is there a way to get the size of an array without knowing the type?

Tags: java, arrays, casting, instanceof

My Object param can either be an `int[]` array or an `Integer[]` array.
Is there a way to determine the size without having to manually check if its a `int[]` or `Integer[]` type?

`int length = ((Object[]) param).length`
does not work for `int[]` (it causes a ClassCastException)

My current approach is to use:

`int length = param instanceof  int[] ? ((int[]) param).length : ((Integer[]) param).length;`

I wonder if there might be a way to cast param that works in both cases, so I can avoid having to check manually every time.

edit: I accidentally used both "x" and "param" to name my variable. Now Im only using "param" to make the question less confusing.

Comment: Why are you trying to cast it in the first place? Just doing `param.length` should work for all arrays irrespective of their type. Do you get an error?

Comment: To add to that, why would you ever have an `Integer[]` to begin with? It would be functionally identical to `int[]` but with a ridiculously much larger memory footprint. There is nothing you gain by having an Integer object array,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use [`Array.getLength()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#getLength(java.lang.Object))

```
Object x; // assuming it’s an array
int length = Array.getLength(x);
```